# .Net problem "Illegal characters in path."

Tags: .net, asp.net

Hi all ok I'm not a .net developer I'm from a PHP, python background and I'm not sure what to do with this.

I have the following error when trying to load one of our sites. Please can someone help

`[ArgumentException: Illegal characters in path.]
   System.IO.Path.CheckInvalidPathChars(String path) +7491109
   System.IO.Path.GetFileName(String path) +19
   System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize) +16
   System.Xml.XmlDownloadManager.GetStream(Uri uri, ICredentials credentials) +77
   System.Xml.XmlUrlResolver.GetEntity(Uri absoluteUri, String role, Type ofObjectToReturn) +54
   System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.OpenUrlDelegate(Object xmlResolver) +74
   System.Threading.CompressedStack.runTryCode(Object userData) +70
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.ExecuteCodeWithGuaranteedCleanup(TryCode code, CleanupCode backoutCode, Object userData) +0
   System.Threading.CompressedStack.Run(CompressedStack compressedStack, ContextCallback callback, Object state) +108
   System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.OpenUrl() +186
   System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Read() +208
   System.Xml.XPath.XPathDocument.LoadFromReader(XmlReader reader, XmlSpace space) +217
   System.Xml.XPath.XPathDocument..ctor(String uri, XmlSpace space) +116
   System.Xml.XPath.XPathDocument..ctor(String uri) +6
   OpenBay.Utils.XPathUtils.GetNodes(String xpathQuery, String xmlFile) +30
   OpenBay.Wms.Controllers.SiteController.SetErrorPages(Site site) +21
   OpenBay.Wms.Controllers.SiteController.GetSite(Uri uri, DirectoryInfo dir, String applicationName) +104
   OpenBay.Wms.HttpModule.UrlProcessHttpModule.GetSiteParameters(HttpApplication app, RequestInfo info) +172
   OpenBay.Wms.HttpModule.UrlProcessHttpModule.ProcessRequest(Object o, EventArgs args) +338
   System.Web.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +68
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +75`

thanks guys

Comment: It would be more helpful if you provided the pathname so we can look for the characters that are not allowed.

Answer (score 7):

Your code will call `System.IO.Path.CheckInvalidPathChars`, which in turn checks for the the following:

1. double quote (")
2. left angle bracket (<)
3. right angle bracket (>)
4. veritical bar (|)

and for control characters less than 32 decimal (space).

So Make sure your path doesn't contain them.

**Edit:** 
[comment from Guy Lowe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1741560/net-problem-illegal-characters-in-path/1741571?noredirect=1#comment59059741_1741571)

> my issue was my unescaped \ in c:\ making it c:\ fixed it

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure where System.IO.Path.CheckInvalidPathChars is. Where would I locate this?

Comment: You will locate this inside the  `System.IO.Path` namespace, the important thing is to make sure that your path doesn't contain the above characters.

Comment: You need to import the `System.IO` namespace before using the `Path` class (no need for referencing any dll as it is declared in mscorlib)

Comment: @Ngu: Path is a class, not a namespace.

Comment: `CheckInvalidPathChars` is internal, you can't use it from outside (Nitpicker's corner: *without reflection*).

Comment: my issue was my unescaped \ in c:\ making it c:\\ fixed it.

Comment: How can I see the path value?

Comment: nvm, saw it in my error, "System.Web.HttpContext.GetFilePathData()"

Comment: I have same issue : where i can edit this path value ? in environment variables ? (I am React Developer so don't have that much idea about .net)

Answer (score 0):

Nice Stacktrace, but the invalid path would be more helpful.

In my oponion, the path provided to OpenBay.Utils.XPathUtils.GetNodes(string, string) has some invalid arguments. Use System.IO.Path.CheckInvalidPathChars() to check which characters are invalid and maybe contained in the argument provided to the method above.

Comment: Sorry the path is just the domain root we haven't changed anything on the site for a long while so this is out of the blue. Where is Use System.IO.Path.CheckInvalidPathChars() located?

Answer (score 0):

Please look at this link, I am using VS 2019:
[VS Test cases issue, NUnit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49337947/visual-studio-2017-net-core-2-tests-not-executable/67333752#67333752)